# How entrySet() works internally in HashMap?

Tags: java, iterator, hashmap

I am trying to understand entrySet() function in HashMap but I am not sure how it is working and from where the values are being populated when creating new EntrySet().

```
public Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> entrySet() {
    return entrySet0();
}

private Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> entrySet0() {
    Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> es = entrySet;
    return es != null ? es : (entrySet = new EntrySet());
}
```

Comment: If you're looking at the `HashMap` code, look for the definition of the inner class `EntrySet` in `HashMap`. It is actually a live view of the contents of the map.

Comment: Thanks @khelwood:)
Are you referring to this --

`code`

    // Views

    private transient Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> entrySet = null;

`code`

But I didn't get the live view part :( ..Can you explain this :)

Comment: No. The part that says `private final class EntrySet`

Comment: You can refer this source code http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.Entry.

Comment: You can refer this [`link`](http://javahungry.blogspot.com/2013/08/hashing-how-hash-map-works-in-java-or.html) to know how internally it works. You can [`Google`](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=how+hashmap+works&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=zTR1Vfy_IqSwmwXerYFg) it, there is plenty of material available.

Answer (score 5):

The following is the source code of entrySet() in jdk8:

```
public Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> entrySet() {
    Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> es;
    return (es = entrySet) == null ? (entrySet = new EntrySet()) : es;
}

final class EntrySet extends AbstractSet<Map.Entry<K,V>> {
    public final int size()                 { return size; }
    public final void clear()               { HashMap.this.clear(); }
    public final Iterator<Map.Entry<K,V>> iterator() {
        return new EntryIterator();//get the iterator
    }
    public final boolean contains(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof Map.Entry))
            return false;
        Map.Entry<?,?> e = (Map.Entry<?,?>) o;
        Object key = e.getKey();
        Node<K,V> candidate = getNode(hash(key), key);
        return candidate != null && candidate.equals(e);
    }
    public final boolean remove(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Map.Entry) {
            Map.Entry<?,?> e = (Map.Entry<?,?>) o;
            Object key = e.getKey();
            Object value = e.getValue();
            return removeNode(hash(key), key, value, true, true) != null;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public final Spliterator<Map.Entry<K,V>> spliterator() {
        return new EntrySpliterator<>(HashMap.this, 0, -1, 0, 0);
    }
    public final void forEach(Consumer<? super Map.Entry<K,V>> action) {
        Node<K,V>[] tab;
        if (action == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        if (size > 0 && (tab = table) != null) {
            int mc = modCount;
            for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; ++i) {
                for (Node<K,V> e = tab[i]; e != null; e = e.next)
                    action.accept(e);
            }
            if (modCount != mc)
                throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        }
    }
}
```

First: when we use entrySet() method, it return new EntrySet(), which is an instance of EntrySet. And this class has a iterator() method, which can be used in for ...loop. And the iterator() method return an iterator(class: EntryIterator)

Second: we read the source code of final class EntryIterator:

```
final class EntryIterator extends HashIterator implements Iterator<Map.Entry<K,V>> {
    public final Map.Entry<K,V> next() { return nextNode(); }
}
```

From the code, we can see it implements next() method. And it return nextNode();

Third: we read the source code of nextNode method (it is in HashIterator class):

```
abstract class HashIterator {
    Node<K,V> next;        // next entry to return
    Node<K,V> current;     // current entry
    int expectedModCount;  // for fast-fail
    int index;             // current slot

    HashIterator() { //when new EntryIterator, this will load data first.
        expectedModCount = modCount;
        Node<K,V>[] t = table;
        current = next = null;
        index = 0;
        if (t != null && size > 0) { // advance to first entry
            do {} while (index < t.length && (next = t[index++]) == null);
        }
    }

    public final boolean hasNext() {
        return next != null;
    }

    final Node<K,V> nextNode() {
        Node<K,V>[] t;
        Node<K,V> e = next;
        if (modCount != expectedModCount)
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        if (e == null)
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        if ((next = (current = e).next) == null && (t = table) != null) {
            do {} while (index < t.length && (next = t[index++]) == null);
        }
        return e;
    }

    public final void remove() {
        Node<K,V> p = current;
        if (p == null)
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        if (modCount != expectedModCount)
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        current = null;
        K key = p.key;
        removeNode(hash(key), key, null, false, false);
        expectedModCount = modCount;
    }
}
```

> According to the order of new an Object. It will use the constructor function >based on the order: Object ---> Superclass ---> the last will be itself
>
> jsut like : new HashIterator() then new EntryIterator()
>
> when new EntryIterator(), it will use HashIterator's constructor
>   method before itself. We can see **it will load the data of HashMap** when
>   we use HashIterator's constructor method.

And nextNode() method get the data from these data. So we can use for ... loop to get all node of HashMap Object.

Answer (score 2):

> where the values are being populated when creating new EntrySet()

The EntrySet you are looking at in HashMap.java is not a new collection, rather it is a functional wrapper *backed by the HashMap itself* (read the javadoc).

The operation upon the EntrySet are delegated to the HashMap itself.

Therefore, EntrySet doesn't actually hold anything. The EntrySet doesn't need to be populated.

From the source:

```
private final class EntrySet extends AbstractSet<Map.Entry<K,V>> {
    public Iterator<Map.Entry<K,V>> iterator() {
        return newEntryIterator();
    }
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof Map.Entry))
            return false;
        Map.Entry<K,V> e = (Map.Entry<K,V>) o;
        Entry<K,V> candidate = getEntry(e.getKey());
        return candidate != null && candidate.equals(e);
    }
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        return removeMapping(o) != null;
    }
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }
    public void clear() {
        HashMap.this.clear();
    }
}
```

As you can see, the class isn't a collection, but rather a *view* of the actual Map.

Comment: Thanks xTrollxDudex for the detailed answer ...Really helped :)

As you mentioned  -

EntrySet class has _this_ ( HashMap ) object which it uses internally

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B22APPjD496tYWhWaFlCXzBFTG8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Indeed, you are correct. Although I'm not sure if non-static inner classes *all* have the `this` instance stored with it as well :P

Comment: What I found interesting is this: The entrySet, an instance field of the HashMap, is just a HashSet with its HashMap field set to, well, this HashMap (`HashMap.this`, which contains the entrySet).   <-- I hope this made sense - not sure how to word it in a non-roundabout way.

Answer (score 1):

[Source](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/HashMap.java.html#961)

Inside `HashMap` there is an inner class

```
private final class EntrySet extends AbstractSet...
```

This is what is returned by the `entrySet()` method in `HashMap`.

When you call a method in the `EntrySet` class to examine its contents, it looks up the information in the `HashMap`. If you add or remove items in the `EntrySet`, it will affect the `HashMap` (and vice versa). It is essentially just another way of looking at the same container. It does not have its own copy of the `Map`'s contents.

Comment: Can you please help me to find the code for the look up part ?

Answer (score 0):

The entrySet() method is used to get a Set view of the mappings contained in this map.

So, this will return you the set representation of values stored in the Map but this is linked with Map so during iteration of Map if you change anything it will be reflected in Set.

On the other hand The set supports element removal, which removes the corresponding mapping from the map, via the Iterator.remove, Set.remove, removeAll, retainAll and clear operations. It does not support the add or addAll operations.

Checkout this example to get details on how it works.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/hashmap_entryset.htm

Answer (score 0):

you can think in the way that you put < key, value > into a set. It's convenient to traverse the map.

```
for (Map.Entry me: map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("key" + me.getKey() + " value" + me.getValue());
}
```

instead of using key to find the value in the map

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

the entryset is not need populated the values,if you call iterator()，it will call
newEntryIterator(),

```
private final class EntrySet extends AbstractSet<Map.Entry<K,V>> {
    public Iterator<Map.Entry<K,V>> iterator() {
        return newEntryIterator();
    }
}
Iterator<Map.Entry<K,V>> newEntryIterator()   {
    return new EntryIterator();
}
private final class EntryIterator extends HashIterator<Map.Entry<K,V>> {
    public Map.Entry<K,V> next() {
        return nextEntry();
    }
}
final Entry<K,V> nextEntry() {
        if (modCount != expectedModCount)
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        Entry<K,V> e = next;
        if (e == null)
            throw new NoSuchElementException();

        if ((next = e.next) == null) {
            Entry[] t = table;
            while (index < t.length && (next = t[index++]) == null)
                ;
        }
        current = e;
        return e;
    }
```